# Porting a 1.7 theme to 2.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, magento2, theme

I have a templatemonster theme for 1.7 and am trying to port it to 2.0.2. Is there any documentation on how to do this? What goes where, etc? I know I will likely have to modify includes and the files themselves. I am curious if anyone else has had to do this before?

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2's template system (and templates) is completely different from Magento 1.x. Which is to say, what you will have to do is nothing short of a complete theme build. You probably can't reuse anything from the theme directly, and it will be time consuming.

The official documentation covering theming is here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Good luck!